# resolving @Value in imported spring @Configuration

Tags: spring, configuration

I have changed the original answer, because it was not complete. The updated answer follows here:

I would like to autowire Resource file in the test @Configuration. The scenario is as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)                                                                                                                                             
@ContextConfiguration(classes = TestConfiguration.class)                                                                                                                 
public class FooTest {                                                                                                                                                   

    @Test                                                                                                                                                                
    public void foo() {                                                                                                                                                  
    }                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                        


@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class TestConfiguration extends BaseConfiguration {

    @Value("classpath:derby-db.sql")
    private Resource dbScript;

    @Bean
    public Object foo() {
        log.info("{}", dbScript);
        return new Object();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }
}


public abstract class BaseConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("foo")
    protected Object foo;

    protected abstract Object getFoo();
}
```

However, the scenario does not work. Reference to the `dbScript` is null while initializing bean `foo`. 
If I move the protected autowired field named `foo` out of `BaseConfiguration` and put it to the top-level `TestConfiguration`, everything works as expected and the `dbScript` reference is initialized.

Could someone please explain this behaviour?

Thanks for reply.

Miro

Answer (score 0):

@Value annotation is used to inject value of a property. If you want to initialize Resource object then use @PropertySource(value="classpath:xxxxx.properties") annotation above class name.